# LangChain with VectorDB retrieval, is unaware of common knowledge

Tags: langchain, langchain-js

My goal is to make ChatGPT answer my questions while taking my personal documents in account, but also using the knowledge it already has.

I loaded the documents like this:

```
import {PDFLoader} from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/pdf";
import {TextLoader} from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/text";
import {DirectoryLoader} from "langchain/document_loaders/fs/directory";

const loader = new DirectoryLoader('data',
    {
       '.txt': filePath => new TextLoader(filePath),
       '.pdf': filePath => new PDFLoader(filePath),
    })
const docs = await loader.load();
```

Next, I've sent that information to a database.

```
import {CharacterTextSplitter} from "langchain/text_splitter";
import {OpenAIEmbeddings} from "langchain/embeddings/openai";
import {Chroma} from "langchain/vectorstores/chroma";

const textSplitter = new CharacterTextSplitter({chunkSize: 2000, chunkOverlap: 200});
const splitDocs = await textSplitter.splitDocuments(docs);
const vectorDB = await Chroma.fromDocuments(splitDocs, new OpenAIEmbeddings({openAIApiKey}), {collectionName: 'belgium1'});
```

And finally, I created an OpenAI model, and inserted the vectorDB as a retriever in it.

```
import {OpenAI} from "langchain/llms/openai";
import {RetrievalQAChain} from "langchain/chains";

const openAIApiKey = '...';
const model = new OpenAI({temperature: 0, openAIApiKey});
const chain = RetrievalQAChain.fromLLM(model, vectorDB.asRetriever());
```

It works fine, when I ask questions within the context of my documents.
But when I ask general questions outside that scope, it answers "I don't know".

```
const result = await chain.run('Who is Donald Duck?');
```

What am I missing?
It seems like it does no longer use the knowledge of ChatGPT.
Is there something wrong with the `RetrievalQAChain`?

Comment: I've not used the JS version of this library, but doesn't the [default prompt](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchainjs/blob/main/langchain/src/chains/question_answering/stuff_prompts.ts#L13) for RetrievalQAChain tell it to only answer the question using the provided context?

Comment: Here's the description of the `RetrievalQA` method: `Chain for question-answering against an index` the chain also comes with a default prompt that explicitly asks the model not to generate answers beyond the index/context. You could modify the prompt entirely to suit your needs. Take a look at this https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/3115 it's for the Python version but I'm pretty sure you could do the same using the TS library.

Answer (score 0):

from what I am able to understand about your problem is that you want answers from your documents as well as additional knowledge from the model itself.

In Langchain you can use **Agents** for this - [Link](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/)

You can also do **Prompt customization** like [this](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/agent_types/openai_functions_agent)

Example image:
[image]

In the prefix you can tell what you want you model to do and do not do. For example:
[image]

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For your case, the best approach would be:

- Create a vector-db-based retriever is a tool made available in the chain.
  The LLM would decide which tool to use based on the user's input.

More details here: https://js.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/question_answering/conversational_retrieval_agents

In this way, if the user's input matches the vector database content, the system responds using that data. Otherwise, it answers from its knowledge base.